# Store functions with parameters in a List

Tags: c#

I want to store functions with parameters in a List, so that I can call them at a later stage.

Let's say (this is rough code)

```
void Func1(int index)
{
   Debug.Log("Func1"+index)
}

void Func2(int index)
{
   Debug.Log("Func2"+index)
}
.
.
.

void Store(Func1(1))
{
  list.Add(Func1(1));
}

void Replay(int position)
{
  list[position](); // this calls the function with the parameter
}
```

Comment: use a [lambda expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions): `Action f = () => Func1 (1);  f ();`

Comment: @trollingchar Sorry I quite not understand by what you mean. Can you please elaborate. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declare that you have a list of actions:

```
List<Action> list;
```

Do not forget to initialize it:

```
list = new List<Action>();
```

Then, you create an action from the function using a lambda expression:

```
Action action = () => Func1(1);
```

And you add the action to the list:

```
list.Add(action);
```

You can, of course, inline the lambda expression:

```
list.Add(() => Func1(1));
```

Afterwards you can call the actions, for example, in a loop:

```
foreach (var action in list)
{
    action.Invoke();
}
```

Actually, you do not need to use `Invoke`:

```
foreach (var action in list)
{
    action();
}
```

Ah, yes, that works too:

```
list[position]();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer, will try it and let you know :)